# Christmas themed layout?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design

Tis the season to have at least one snowman in the background of every site! It would go along with the hat event, and would fill us all with glee!

Comment: Isn't Meta being infested with all these holiday questions enough? -.-

Comment: What is the question here ?

Comment: Alternate proposal: Make green tags to supplement the red tags.

Answer (score 7):

We have one designer and 90 sites. Even if you subtract the beta ones that share a design (which admittedly are the majority right now), that's still too many and we're not even talking about all the *other* projects and tasks on the go.

Sorry, but this isn't happening this year.

Comment: ah well, maybe next year